# Ignoring 301 Permanent Redirect with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, http, redirect, nsurlconnection

An API that i'm using that I don't control is using a 301 permanent redirect when it shouldn't be. I need my NSURLConnection to ignore the fact that its been permanently redirected in the past for future requests.

Heres an example for Clarity.

I'm connecting to http://stupidapi.com/users/frank/profilepicture. It does a 301 redirect to http://profilepictures.stupidapi.com/52435346324 which has the profile picture i'm looking for at it.

So lets say that later Frank logs into his account and changes his profile picture. Now when I want the new profile picture I go to http://stupidapi.com/users/frank/profilepicture but since the first request I made was a 301 permanent redirect it sends me back to http://profilepictures.stupidapi.com/52435346324 which is the old picture. If it was my first time requesting it would've sent me to http://profilepictures.stupidapi.com/34535476557 for the new picture.

How do I get NSURLConnection to always go to the newest version of the picture?

I've tried setting the NSURLRequest cache policy to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCache

```
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCache;
```

I've also tried clearing the NSURLCache before any request is made with

```
[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

Neither have worked so far. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What about `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:request]`?

Comment: Tried it, same results. Is stuff like this actually cached by the system? It seems like even if I delete my app and re-install it, I still get redirected to the old version.

Comment: Does Safari load it with no issue?

Comment: Have you checked the actual request sent, it could be caching in a router, etc. A quick check with Charles Proxy might help.

Comment: Gotcha, i'm starting to think that the API i'm connecting to has more going on than just this issue. I'm getting inconsistent results on safari too, but it looks like they are the "same" inconsistencies that i'm getting on the iPhone. Its possible clearing the cache actually fixes the 301 issue on the phone but something else is caching it on the network or the api i'm connecting to is doing weird stuff behind the scenes. I'll keep testing.

Comment: Charles would just tell me the request being sent from my iPhone right? If the router is caching it and just sending the redirect url straight to the internet i'd never know unless I use a proxy outside of my current network.. Might have to set that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out a nasty hack of a solution, but its the best I could come up with.

The original URL specified doesn't care about capitalization so basically every time I send a request to it, I randomly set each letter in a specific part of the url to either uppercase or lowercase.

Basically instead of just going to http://stupidapi.com/users/frank/profilepicture I got to http://stupidapi.com/users/FrAnk/profilepicture. If I hit one that hasn't been cached already then I get the new picture.

For my particular use case, this works well enough.